# How to make scroll bar auto scroll to one item selected?

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollview

I have 2 questions about Winphone 8 UI Control:

- How to make textbox non-editable with a color not gray-color?
- If I have scrollview, there are many textbox inside, when I set foreground for one of this, I want to scrolllview auto scroll to this position(that item is out of view) to visible this item? (like listview)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To make the `textbox` non-editable give the `IsReadOnly` property as true.

XAML:

```
<TextBox 
IsReadOnly="True"
>
The user may not modify the contents of this TextBox.
</TextBox>
```